# gdb skips breakpoints without sudo

Tags: permissions, gdb

I'm trying to debug simple 8-line program with gdb:

```
$ g++ -g 1.cpp
$ gdb a.out
(gdb) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40089e: file 1.cpp, line 5.
(gdb) run
```

However, gdb will just skip over the breakpoint and process just executes and exits normally.

But, if I run `sudo gdb a.out`, then it will stop on breakpoint as expected. I even tried setting setuid bit on gdb executable, but even that didn't help.

Additional info:

```
$ sudo sysctl --all | grep yama
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0

$ stat `which gdb`
  File: '/usr/bin/gdb'
  Size: 6546408     Blocks: 12792      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 19136921    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2017-05-05 16:04:28.364144348 +0300
Modify: 2016-06-23 22:55:06.000000000 +0300
Change: 2017-05-05 16:04:16.771898651 +0300
 Birth: -

$ gdb
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) show config
This GDB was configured as follows:
   configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
             --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
             --with-expat
             --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/share/gdb (relocatable)
             --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/lib/gdb (relocatable)
             --without-libunwind-ia64
             --with-lzma
             --with-python=/usr (relocatable)
             --without-guile
             --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug (relocatable)
             --with-system-gdbinit=/etc/gdb/gdbinit
             --with-babeltrace
```

I'm out of ideas. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if this is specific to using `sudo` or if it is just something to do with your normal user. Can you try creating a new user and then running the gdb as that user? Does that work as expected?

Comment: @terdon, you are right. I ran `sudo adduser test1` and tried to use gdb as that user and it worked. Thanks. Now I'm very curious what is the difference.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about gdb to answer that. I assume it checks some configuration file. Is there a `~/.gdb` or `~/.config/gdb` file or directory? Is the output for `which gdb` and `sudo which gdb` the same?

Comment: @terdon it seems to be related to that I use fish as my shell and I use script `#!/bin/bash -l
fish "$@"` as my login shell

Comment: Wait what? Why in the world would you do that instead of just setting fish as your default with `chsh`? Either way, you need to find where you are setting whatever it is you are setting that controls/changes the behavior of gdb. I really doubt that your shell itself would be relevant. Have you tried starting different shells and running the gdb command?

Comment: I did that hack so that `fish` will load env variables from .profile file (fish is incompatible with bash). If I `chsh` login shell back to bash, then gdb works normally.  Just running invoking bash from fish is not enough.

Comment: Try compiling with `-O0`. I don't know if the shell has anything to do with this, like @terdon said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reasons unclear to me gdb uses SHELL environment variable.
If I run it like this:

```
$ env SHELL=/bin/bash gdb a.out
```

gdb stops at breakpoints as expected.

Comment: thanks to @terdon for pointing out the right direction to look for solution.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I strongly urge you to change tack though. Instead of having bash call fish, just have fish source .profile if that's what you need.

Comment: @terdon, that's the problem. fish can't execute bash syntax.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. I still feel that the way you're doing it (a very clever hack, by the way) is not the best approach. You could maybe modify your fish init file to run something like `sed -nE 's/(.*?)=(.*)/set \1 "\2"/p' ~/.profile > /tmp/foo; and . /tmp/foo`. This would be a very interesting question for the site, actually. I suggest you ask this on [unix.se], I'm sure we can find a neat trick for you that doesn't have the issues your approach has.